# permissions - slacken rule for sites in beta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, tagging

Asking questions on the newer stackexchange sites, such as this one, has been rather frustrating for me because the tags I would like to use are simply not there yet. For now, I have just forgone using those tags.

I propose that permissions to create tags be granted to more people. Perhaps using total rep across all sites (as seen in http://area51.stackexchange.com ) as an alternative means of obtaining those permissions.

This suggestion of course has far broader implications than just tags, so comments and alternative ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: if you really think you need a new tag you could leave a comment on your question, its likely one of the moderators will see it and add the tag to your question if its a valid request

Comment: @Jaips : Thanks for that, will definitely do

Answer (score 4):

The requirements are relaxed for public beta (what this is) and private beta (the very first week).

Details at

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

Specifically:

```
Action                                          Priv ß Public ß  Golden       SO
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Create new tags                                      1      150     200     1500
```

Considering you get 101 rep for existing and having +200 in the network anywhere, we don't feel 150 rep is a major limitation.

Also bear in mind that creating new tags can be kind of harmful when done incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the link - It appears that global rep has been used only to determine chat privileges.
I suggest that global rep be used for other permissions as well: e.g. in Public ß, you need 150 rep OR 2k global rep to create a tag.
IMHO those with high global rep are unlikely to create harmful tags.

Comment: @bgu there is no concept of "global rep" that I know of. You get a +100 for having +200 somewhere in the network on a new site you join; that's it.

Comment: "we don't feel 105 rep is a major limitation" - should that read 150?